# capturar item selecionado DropDownList criado em javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, webforms

Ola pessoal alguém poderia me ajudar.
estou com o seguinte problema tenho um TextBox e um DropDownList, no textbox tem um autocomplete com nomes de estados; apos finalizar preenchimento do textbox preenche DropDownList com nomes das cidades correspondente aquele estado. ate ai tudo funcionando corretamente. 
a dificuldade na qual me deparei foi em recuperar o código da cidade no evento do Button

segue o código abaixo

---

javascript

---

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        populaDropDownList();
        volume();
    });

    function populaDropDownList() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/getDados",
            data: "{'CountryName':'" + $("#txtEstado").val() + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {

                var Dropdown = $('#<%=dpdCidades.ClientID%>');
                Dropdown.empty();
                //$(Dropdown).empty();
                Dropdown.append(new Option("Selecione", 0));
                $.each(response.d, function (index, item) {
                    Dropdown.append(new Option(item.Nome, item.Id));
                });

            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Falha ao carregar dados");
            }
        });
```

}

```
    function volume() {
        $("#txtEstado").autocomplete({
            //DropDownList
            change: function () {
                populaDropDownList();
            },
            //AutoComplete
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "Default.aspx/getEstado",
                    data: "{'CountryName':'" + $("#txtEstado").val() + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response(data.d);
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert("Error");
                    }
                });
            }
        });


        }
```

//**************
Default.aspx
//*****************

```
  <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
            </asp:ScriptManager>
            <div>     
                        <p>
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtEstado" Width="120">
                            </asp:TextBox>
                        </p>

                        <p>
                            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="dpdCidades" Width="120"></asp:DropDownList>
                            <asp:Label Text="" ID="msg" runat="server" />
                        </p>

                <p>
                    <asp:Button Text="Pesquisar" runat="server" ID="lblPesquisar" OnClick="Unnamed1_Click" />

                </p>


            </div>
```

---

Default.aspxcs

---

```
    [WebMethod]
            public static List<Cidade> getDados(string CountryName)
            {
                var con = new Conexao();
                var estado = new Estado();
                estado.Nome = CountryName;
                var lst = con.ListatodasCidades(estado).ToList();
                return lst.ToList();
            }
            [WebMethod]
            public static List<string> getEstado(string CountryName)
            {
                var con = new Conexao();
                var estado = new Estado();
                var strLstEstado = new List<string>();
                estado.Nome = CountryName;
                var lst = con.ListaEstados(estado).ToList();
                foreach (var item in lst)
                {
                    strLstEstado.Add(item.Nome);
                }
                return strLstEstado.ToList();
            }
  protected void Unnamed1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var teste1 = dpdCidades.SelectedValue;
            var teste12 = dpdCidades.SelectedItem;
            var teste13 = dpdCidades.Text;
            var s4 = string.IsNullOrEmpty(dpdCidades.Text) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(dpdCidades.Text);
            PopularGrid();
        }
```

Perceba que no evento do buttom "Unnamed1_Click" fiz testes de toda a forma mais sempre vem vazio sem nenhum item selecionado, e quando eu crio uma funçao javascript com um alert ele pega o id perfeito, sera que nessa situação ele pega só via javascript mesmo? Logo abaixo é exemplo do alert de teste na qual estou pegando perfeito o id da cidade no DropDownList

```
 function myFunction() {
            var DropdownList = document.getElementById('<%=dpdCidades.ClientID %>');

            //var SelectedIndex = DropdownList.selectedIndex;
            var SelectedValue = DropdownList.value;

            alert(SelectedValue);           

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui com a seguinte solução

---

Code behind

---

```
protected void Unnamed1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            var ss = hdnResultValue.Value;
            //PopularGrid();
        }
```

---

```
javascript
```

---

```
         function setHiddenField() {

            debugger;
            var DropdownList = document.getElementById("dpdCidades");
            var SelectedValue = DropdownList.value;
            document.getElementById('hdnResultValue').value = SelectedValue;
            //alert(SelectedValue);
        }
```

---

Default.aspx

---

```
         <asp:Button Text="Pesquisar" runat="server" ID="lblPesquisar" OnClick="Unnamed1_Click"   OnClientClick="setHiddenField()"/>
```